# Google Action list type visuals not working correctly when clicked for the first time

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, vui

I have implemented a List action visual on my google action. When I click on a list item, the related intent should fire, but on the very first click, it goes to default fallback intent.

I suppose it is because the output context is not attached when the list item is clicked, but not sure about that.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That could be the reason, but it is very difficult to tell without any information abut how you're doing it. Please update your questions with pictures of the intents, any code you're using to show the results, screen shots illustrating what is happening, etc. See [Hey Google, I Need Help With My Action](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/hey-google-i-need-help-with-my-action-8cf09714a20d)

Comment: Are you implementing the [actions_intent_OPTION](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#list) intent?

Comment: @NickFelker, I tried with actions_intent_OPTION but it took me to another issue, in this case, only the last option of the list was triggered even if I click on any of the list options.